# Understanding model training and evaluation in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am following a Pytorch code on deep learning. Where I saw model evaluation taking place within the training epoch!

**Q)** Should the torch.no_grad and model.eval() be out of the training epoch loop?

**Q)** And how to determine that, which parameter (weight) are getting optimised by the optimiser during the back-propagation?

...

```
for l in range(1):
    model = GTN(num_edge=A.shape[-1],
                        num_channels=num_channels,w_in = node_features.shape[1],w_out = node_dim,
                        num_class=num_classes,num_layers=num_layers,norm=norm)
    
    if adaptive_lr == 'false':
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.005, weight_decay=0.001)
    else:
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([{'params':model.weight},{'params':model.linear1.parameters()},{'params':model.linear2.parameters()},
                                    {"params":model.layers.parameters(), "lr":0.5}], lr=0.005, weight_decay=0.001)
    
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    # Train & Valid & Test
    best_val_loss = 10000
    best_train_loss = 10000
    best_train_f1 = 0
    best_val_f1 = 0
    
    for i in range(epochs):
        print('Epoch:  ',i+1)
        model.zero_grad()
        model.train()
        loss,y_train,Ws = model(A, node_features, train_node, train_target)
        train_f1 = torch.mean(f1_score(torch.argmax(y_train.detach(),dim=1), train_target, num_classes=num_classes)).cpu().numpy()
        print('Train - Loss: {}, Macro_F1: {}'.format(loss.detach().cpu().numpy(), train_f1))
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        model.eval()
        # Valid

        with torch.no_grad():
            val_loss, y_valid,_ = model.forward(A, node_features, valid_node, valid_target)
            val_f1 = torch.mean(f1_score(torch.argmax(y_valid,dim=1), valid_target, num_classes=num_classes)).cpu().numpy()

        if val_f1 > best_val_f1:
            best_val_loss = val_loss.detach().cpu().numpy()
            best_train_loss = loss.detach().cpu().numpy()
            best_train_f1 = train_f1
            best_val_f1 = val_f1

    print('---------------Best Results--------------------')
    print('Train - Loss: {}, Macro_F1: {}'.format(best_train_loss, best_train_f1))
    print('Valid - Loss: {}, Macro_F1: {}'.format(best_val_loss, best_val_f1))
    final_f1 += best_test_f1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For each epoch, you are doing train, followed by validation/test.
   For validation/test you are moving the model to evaluation model
   using `model.eval()` and then doing forward propagation with
   `torch.no_grad()` which is correct. Again, you are moving back the
   model back to train model using `model.train()` at the start of
   train. There is no issue with the code and you are using the model
   modes correctly.
2. **In your code**, if `adaptive_lr` if False then you are optimizing the parameters given by `model.parameters()` and when `adaptive_lr`
   is True then you are optimizing:

   - `model.weight`
   - `model.linear1.parameters()`
   - `model.linear2.parameters()`
   - `model.layers.parameters()`

Comment: Should it not be that, first finish the training an optimise the parameters. Now start `model.eval()`?

Additionally, is `model.parameters()` a preset parameter list of the `model.py` module which has a `GTN` class which inherits from `nn.Module` ?

Also, we have defined `self.linear1 = nn.Linear(self.w_out*self.num_channels, self.w_out)` in the `model`. Does `model.linear1.parameters()` a predefined parameters list of this `nn.Linear` definition?

Comment: Normally we do one epoch of train (forward and backward prop) followed by an evaluation run to figure out if the model have improved, for example for early stoping etc. model.parameters() will give you all the list of trainable parameter if it is inherited from nn.Moudule.

Comment: Do, `model.weight` , `model.linear1.parameters()` etc. will be contained in `model.parameters()`? Will we get the same `model.parameters()` if we use this using tensorflow? Like can we there write, `grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.parameters())
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.parameters()))`

Comment: If model is derived from nn.module and if linera1 is also a subclass of nn.module then yes. However, In case we want to not optimize few parameters then we selectively supply to the optimizer (which seem to be your second case). However you can also freeze the parameter which need not be optimized and then pass model.parameters() to the optimizer

Comment: If a class is inherting from nn.Module , then in the init method of that class do we need to define any parameter as `self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(w_in, w_out))` ? What about `self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)` does this also add parameters of layers to the list?

Comment: @AnshumanSinha check this https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-how-and-when-to-use-module-sequential-modulelist-and-moduledict-7a54597b5f17